# Multi-schema select statement doesn't work in PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I'm trying to create a procedure to run multiple PL/SQL statements, but I haven't gotten very far. The select statement works fine if I run it out of a procedure, but if I try to execute it inside one -- it can't find the shttran table. I'm guessing it might be a schema issue, but I have no idea how-to correct. Ideas?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REGREPORTUSER.findUnsent
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO regreportuser.maltran (maltran.maltran_key,
                                      maltran.maltran_sent)
      SELECT shttran.shttran_id || shttran.shttran_seq_no AS maltran_key,
             'No' AS maltran_sent
        FROM saturn.shttran -- This is the table it can't find
       WHERE     TO_DATE (shttran.shttran_activity_date) > SYSDATE - 14
             AND shttran.shttran_user = 'WWW2_USER'
             AND shttran.shttran_id || shttran.shttran_seq_no NOT IN
                    (SELECT maltran.maltran_key FROM regreportuser.maltran);
END findUnsent;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that the user that owns the stored procedure, `REGREPORTUSER` has access to the table `saturn.shttran` via a role rather than as a direct grant.  A definer's rights stored procedure cannot use privileges that are granted to a definer via a role.  It can only use privileges granted directly.

You can verify that this is, in fact, the problem by disabling roles in your SQL*Plus session.  If you run the command

```
SQL> set role none;
```

and then try to execute the SQL statement, you should get the same error.  In order to fix the problem, you need to give the grant directly

```
GRANT SELECT ON saturn.shttran
   TO REGREPORTUSER
```